# How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I've got Ubuntu 10.10 installed to use my whole hard-disk, but would like to use the 130GB of free space I've got to create a new partition and do some development on Unity and Natty.

Can I use gparted to do this?  If so how?