# Bigger space for ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, resize

I installed ubuntu 11.10 64bit along side windows. I gave it 19GB but now i'm running out of space.

Is there any "easy" way to make it larger?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with it, I recommend using the Parted Magic Live CD: http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start

After booting the CD, you can use the GPartEd software included to resize the partitions.

**NOTE: BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST!**

Comment: I will check that out. But should i do it from ubuntu or windows? And how can i do a backup, I am very new at ubuntu/linux.

Comment: You can use Dejá Dup to do the backup for Ubuntu- it's installed by default with it. For Windows, I believe it also includes a tool, and some googling should find it for you, though I don't know what it is off hand. With the CD, I'd make it from the Linux side, and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the Gparted tool to do a redimentioned partition of windows.
find him in "System > Administration > Partition editor. or you can download a  live-cd in http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php.

Open Gparted, click on "update devices", click on the partition and then in Redimension.
[EDIT]
From Ubuntu, of course. :)

Comment: I installed GParted but my boot hard drive seems not partitioned

Comment: Did you used Wubi to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I downloaded the cd from ubuntu.com and choose install along side windows.