# How do I reduce the size of my system's root (/) partition?

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition)

How to change partition table on my harddrive.

I want to reduce the size of / partition on 500 GB  hard-drive, currently size of / partition is 250 GB. I want to make it to 150 GB and use the 100 GB for storing my other data.

Current Partition table is as follows:-

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       233G  6.6G  215G   3% /
udev            2.9G  4.0K  2.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  884K  1.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.9G  252K  2.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7        38G  690M   35G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda6        93G  1.6G   87G   2% /boot
/dev/sda5        93G  1.6G   87G   2% /home
```