# Need to create a separate partition after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I've already installed Ubuntu 12.04, but I did not make any separate partitions beside the one the operating system is installed on.

Now I want to make a new partition.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's unlikely that you installed Ubuntu without creating any partition. By default Ubuntu creates two partitions--a partition for the root filesystem, and a swap partition. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you need to create a separate partition? Also, please open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `sudo fdisk -l`, then provide the output by **editing your question**, so we can see what your partition layout looks like currently.

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ed8f3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1936752639   968375296   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1936754686  1953523711     8384513    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1936754688  1953523711     8384512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
ash@ash-System-Product-Name:~$

Comment: As @EliahKagan said, **edit your question** with these details. Please do **not** post comments with additional details like this. After editing your question with the information, please **delete** your comment. Thank you!

Comment: Use Gparted and edit the partitions. You can download it from Ubuntu software center

Comment: Related: [How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition)

Answer (score 8):

### Open gparted via a Live CD

#### Why live cd?

Gparted cannot modify mounted drives and since you only have 1 partition that means it's the one running Ubuntu. So you will have to open the live cd and do your edits from there.

#### What is a live CD?

> live disc is a complete bootable computer operating system which runs in the computer's memory, rather than loading from the hard disk drive. It allows users to experience and evaluate an operating system without installing it or making any changes to the existing operating system on the computer

### How-to

1. Back up your data before fiddling with partitions, just in case.
2. You will need to boot from the live cd (make sure to pick **Try Ubuntu** and not **Install Ubuntu**)
3. Open up gparted and choose to resize the current Linux partition
4. Shrink it from the end (not from the start; it sometimes causes problems)
5. Now that you have shrunk your partition, there will be some empty space at the end of the drive. Right click on it and pick **format**. Choose the filesystem and label for it
6. Press **edit > apply all operations**

Comment: Please expand your answer so that the (possibly inexperienced) OP may *easily* follow the steps outlined.

Comment: If i put the Live cd again will i not lose eveything? ;O

Comment: @user83467, please disregard the above answer until it is clarified for you.

Comment: i updated my answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

If I understand *(correct me if not)* you installed Ubuntu to along all your 1TB HDD.

1. You should [resize your primary partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/126250/62483) (where are Ubuntu installed). The size of this new partition will be of the size that you want to. But remember that it will be limited and your system need have (I recommend you) more than 50GB.
2. Now you will have free space on your disk, this space **must be formatted** so that your system can use it. With the same program that you used for the resize (gparted) you can format that free space. **How to do this:**
   Secondary click on the new partition and choose *format to*. This should give you several options, choice to your preferences. For further information about this formats see [Comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems).

Comment: Forget about comparing file systems. As of now, you want ext4.