# Partion of hard disk

Tags: partitioning

I've install Ubuntu latest version 14 . now I Have completed with installation.
but Have not created disk partition . Pleas guide me how to make Partitions after Installation

Comment: Install Gparted from software center and try partition. If you want to resize the Ubuntu partition then boot from ubuntu live usb and resize it using Gparted.

Comment: you can follow this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/178638/need-to-create-a-partition-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you just want to get more storage for your installation? If this is the case I would recommend you just resizing the current partition of ubuntu.
Ether way here is a short explanation on how to partitioning your disk.

I personally prefer the gparted tool, which can be downloaded by typing:

```
apt-get install gparted
```

in a bash (This needs super user priviliges).
In the upper right corner of this tool should be your disk. It should look like the following: "/dev/sda" or so. Now you can start partitioning...

By selecting one of the partitions in the middle of window and clicking delete you will erase all data on this partition. Be advised to double check if you really want to do that.

After that the deleted part of the disk should be named "unallocated". Now right click and select new and choose whatever you want. I would recommend something like ext4 as the file system. After that just click on the check-mark in the toolbar and gparted will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

To install gparted you must enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

To do it full automatic (if you don't want the Y/n option) use the following command in a termial.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted -y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did a clean install, and used your whole disk for the partition, you really don't need to create another, it just complicates things. If you have a separate drive that has more space or something, then just plug it in with a file manager open and take note of the drive name that appears, rename it to something that you will remember (something other than the default "XXgb volume" or "UUID:XXXXXXXXXXX"). If you want it to mount at boot to, say, a folder in your home folder, then use your livecd to open gparted (or burn an Ubuntu livecd with dparted installed) and find the drive, right click, click on info, and write down the UUID on a piece of paper. Boot back into your main installation and open terminal, type in sudo kate /etc/fstab .Copy the line that has [uuid] / [bunch of modifiers] and then change the uuid to the one you wrote down, and the / to the path to where you want it to mount, save the document and then reboot, it will act like any other folder, but the contents will be installed to the other disk.