# Booting ubuntu from a flash drive while is already being installed on that laptop

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I just installed ubuntu from a usb flash drive last night. As I am a beginner to ubuntu platform so I missed the opportunity to create partitions during installation from the flash drive. Now, I searched the internet and found out that the partitions of the hard drive can be created after ubuntu being installed on your laptop( just like you can shrink and create partitions in windows). The method says that for creating partitions you have to boot form a live stick of ubuntu. Since I installed ubuntu last night I am still having that same Live Usb stick. But when during booting I select the usb drive it is not being selected and when I press enter to the option of booting from usb it automatically goes to default ubuntu install on my laptop. Why is it not being booted from the usb? I am a newbie to ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu creates at least one partition (i.e. the root partition, which is mounted at `/`). Are you talking about creating *additional* partitions?

Comment: You've already created a partition and installed Ubuntu to it. Your real question could be "What size of partition did I create?". Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and type `lsblk` then copy and paste screen output to your question.

Comment: @wjandrea I mean dividing the existing big partition which ubuntu created into smaller partitions.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't want to know the size of partition created by ubuntu. I just want to divide the partition created by ubuntu (i.e in my case it is 931G ) into smaller partitions. Like 3 partitions of 300G

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to create a separate partition after installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178638/need-to-create-a-separate-partition-after-installing-ubuntu)