# File sharing between Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on same machine

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am planning to partition my SSD and install Ubuntu on my machine currently running on Windows. I understand I (obviously) need to install separate versions of applications like firefox, VLC etc.

Can someone please provide insights about data sharing? Files stored in windows can be available for access (with compatible software) in Ubuntu and vice versa?

Comment: I think the best alternative for file sharing between Ubuntu and Windows is to create a separate **`data`** partition with the NTFS file system. You can mount it via a line in the file `/etc/fstab`.

See [details in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098164/cant-see-home-partition-in-other-locations/1098211#1098211)

Comment: Additionally, keep in mind that you'll probably be using different versions of applications. Only use that shared space for simple files like photos or documents. Sharing e.g. the same Thunderbird profile folder will get you into trouble.

Comment: Windows prior to 10 can only see the first partition on a flash drive. For compatibility it is best to make your NTFS Linux/Windows partition sdx1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most quick solution did you have is to create a partition with a filesystem it is compatible with both OS (as my suggestion NTFS is a good choose), like this the data are available on both OS.

In this case you have to think that the files created have to follow the windows rules, you have to consider NTFS as filesystem case insensitive; so a file of folder stored there called `DATA` and another called `data` in the Linux OS are two different path but for the windows OS there have no difference between `DATA` and `data`, also the permission are different between the two OS, so it will make harder to manage permission correctly; as far I remember NTFS partition mounted with ntfs-3g driver give permission rwx to all.