# How to re-partition Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition)

I have a 750 GB hard drive and it's been entirely dedicated to my Ubuntu installation. I want to make 2 100 GB partitions for two other OSes and I'm not sure how to make these partitions. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/18523/62483

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use gparted. Downoad the livecd and burn it to a disk and boot from it.

1) Then make the two partitions for your two new os.

2) Then right click on the partitions & under the manage flags option select boot for the two new partitions.

3) After you do so, install the two new os in the partitions.

4) (This is optional)But it might happen that your os does not boot anymore or all oses does not boot or only one or two oses boot. If these happens -

- boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- connect internet
- open a new Terminal, then type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
- Press Enter.

- Then type:

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
- Press Enter

and select recommended repair.

Now, restart your PC and you are good to go.

Hope this helps you.