# How To Create A Small System Partition For Mythbuntu

Tags: partitioning, mythbuntu

I have Mythbuntu 12.04 running with system files and MythTV recordings in the same partition.  I'd like to repartition the disk (perhaps using a second interim drive) to make a small system partition and a large MythTV recordings only partition on the drive.  How can I go about doing this?

The reason I want to do this is I backup the system by cloning the drive which spends a lot of time unnecessarily cloning the recordings when all I need is a (30G?) system image.  By partitioning the drive I should be able to clone only the system partition saving time and will give me the benefit of allowing multiple system images on the backup drive.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Tell us if some of this post can help you: [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/q/126153/62483) and [How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition)

Comment: Based on these links it looks like gparted will do the job.  Thanks for the pointer.  Now I just need to figure out how big to make the MythTV system partition to allow for future growth/fixes  :-)

Comment: So, the first link or the second one?

Comment: All I needed was a pointer to gparted which both links deal with, so either would have done it.  Thanks.