# how to unmoplease guide me on how to unlock the partition in G parted as I want to allocate space to other Operating system?unt the locked

Tags: unlock

please guide me on how to unlock the partition in G parted as I want to allocate space to other Operating system?

Comment: You can't resize the partition for the OS that you're currently running, while running it. You must use another OS instead. The easiest way is usually to boot from a live CD/DVD/USB, as [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition) explains. By the way, in addition to being unable to modify a partition while booted into the OS installation that it contains, you should really not even make any changes (except to the names of volume labels) to any partitions on the same physical disk as the OS you're running. To be safe, use a live environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by a 'locked' partition, but if you are trying to re-size partitions using gparted, the partition CANNOT BE MOUNTED. Right click on the partition in question and unmount (umount) it. You should then be able to re-size it.

Alan