# Why I have lack of space in root directory?

Tags: 14.04, root, disk-usage

Using OS Ubuntu for 2 days. Everyone says that 8GB is more than enough for root directory but it seems like so soon I will have critical lacks of space in root. I have 256GB hard drive and has distributed space as follow:

- 10GB for /
- 8GB for linux-swap
- 126GB for /home

I thought that root "/" directory needs only for install OS and nothing more so that "/home" is intended for my software, but it seems like my software is placed in "/" directory whenever I install new program. The question is: should I reinstall my OS and allocate more space for "/" directory or I don't understand something because now I have only 2GB free from 10GB of root directory, and I'm afraid when I'm going to install more software it's gonna be full?

Comment: `Everyone says that 8GB is more than enough for root directory` this may have been true 15 years ago, for some people, ... actually even then I would have recommended more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition)

Answer (score 2):

> should I reinstall my OS and allocate more space for "/" directory

You can also "resize" using a live session. 10Gb can be enough though. Just make sure user content is on your /home. If you install MySQL the database will eat up space from / if you leave it as is. Same for Apache and any other server tool.

> or I don't understand something because now I have only 2GB free from 10GB of root directory, and I'm afraid when I'm going to install more software it's gonna be full

Or remove software you do not need. 8Gb is a lot. I hardly get to 7Gb and I do have 3 browsers, Apache and MySQL installed.

Comment: Thanks for advice. My "usr" folder is located not at home but at "/" root directory, how can I relocate "usr" content? Every time I install new software it takes space from my root directory, not from my "./home" as I thought it'll be

Comment: @Partylover move 15Gb over from /home to / ?  Resizing is done from a live session using "gparted". "software" is not user content so goes to  /. And not just into /usr/. There is a whole set of directories software uses depending on the type of software.

Answer (score 1):

Yes when you install software the recommend way follows a filesystem hierarchy.

This is the long version. 
https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf

If you want a summary all the libraries themes expect a certain file path. If for some reason you wanted something as simple as a different cursor theme I think gnome-control center for gnome or something like lxapperacne for lubuntu. If I wanted to change the theme with a program to set the theme. It will look in the directory `/usr/share/icons/` to see what different cursors are available. If you have the files of something as simple as a different cursor theme it starts to really  break things a ton.